# How can we download file(pdf) in android studio from firebase such that it doesn't appear in phone's internal storage?

Tags: java, android

I am developing an application where I need to download pdf files from firebase  storage and store it inside the app(the one I am developing) and these files shouldn't be accessible to user outside my app. I had developed using Firebase code for downloading but it is downloading in the download folder of mobile even after changing the destination directory.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays there are two kinds of storage in an android device: **Internal** and **external**.

According to android docs:

**Internal storage:**

- It's always available.
- Files saved here are accessible by only your app.
- When the user uninstalls your app, the system removes all your app's files from internal storage.

**External storage:**

- It's world-readable, so files saved here may be read outside of your control.
- It's not always available, because the user can mount the external storage as USB storage and in some cases remove it from the device.
- When the user uninstalls your app, the system removes your app's files from here only if you save them in the directory from getExternalFilesDir().

External storage is the best place for files that don't require access restrictions and for files that you want to share with other apps or allow the user to access with a computer.

Internal storage is best when you want to be sure that neither the user nor other apps can access your files.

To get path of internal storage of your app:

```
getFilesDir()
```

This will give you a *File* representing the directory on the file system that's uniquely associated with your app.

Hope it helps!

Source: [Save files on device storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files)

**EDIT:**

If you want the file downloaded from firebase storage to be only visible to your app, you should move the file from downloads to internal storage and then delete the file from downloads